# Error in spec : (df) : inherits(x,"tbl_df") is not true

Tags: r, specifications

Hi I am just trying to run a spec() on my df and keep running into this error

> Error in spec(df) : inherits(x, "tbl_df") is not TRUE

I have absolutely no idea what it means, and my df is utterly unremarkable as far as I can tell.

Can someone please explain to me what the error means so that I can start troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: `spec` only works on tibbles of class `spec_tbl_df`.

There are several functions named `spec()`. You should mention that this one is from the `readr` package.

The documentation for `readr::spec` states:

```
spec() extracts the full column specification from a tibble created by readr.
```

In other words, it does not work on a regular data frame: it has to be a tibble and more than that, a tibble created by a `readr` function such as `read_csv`.

Some examples:

```
class(iris)
[1] "data.frame"

readr::spec(iris)
# not a tibble
Error in readr::spec(iris) : inherits(x, "tbl_df") is not TRUE

class(as_tibble(iris))
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
readr::spec(as_tibble(iris))
# it is a tibble but not created by readr
NULL
```

A fake example for a CSV file with 3 columns `charge`, `old`, `new`.

```
library(readr)
mydata <- read_csv("mydata.csv")
class(mydata)
[1] "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame" 

spec(mydata)
# now it works; it's a tibble with class spec_tbl_df
cols(
  charge = col_character(),
  old = col_double(),
  new = col_double()
)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, that is very clear (apologies for not specifying that I was using the function from readr) 

If I wanted to achieve the effects of readr::spec, is there another function that I could use? Or would I have to write.csv then read_csv() for the data frame in question?

ps. I cannot upvote because my reputation is garbage but would love to vote for your answer, thanks again :)

Comment: Yes I think you need `read_csv` for `spec`, I don't know of a similar function. You should be able to accept the answer regardless of reputation I think, even if you can't upvote.

Comment: ahaha and you have taught me something about how SO works as well, what an arvo!
Thanks again :)